# I got = removeChild is not a function

Tags: javascript, dom

I've trying to remove the disk as a child from a tower as a parent, but this message appears "removeChild is not a function".

```js
let chosenDisc
let chosenTower

disks.forEach((choice) =>
  choices.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    chosenDisc  = e.target.id
    chosenTower = e.target.parentElement.id
    console.log(chosenDisc, " is in ", chosenTower)
    chosenTower.removeChild(chosenDisc)
    container.appendChild(chosenDisc)
  })
)
```

```html
<article class="container"></article>
<section class="towers">
  <div class="tower" id="towerOne">
    <div class="disk" id="diskOne"></div>
    <div class="disk" id="diskTwo"></div>
    <div class="disk" id="diskThree"></div>
    <div class="disk" id="diskFour"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tower" id="torreTwo"></div>
  <div class="tower" id="torreThree"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: You set chosenTower to be the ID of the element (a string). A string won't have a method removeChild. (also, you attempt to stuff another ID into it and not an element.)

Comment: [what `disks` is supposed to be ?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are attaching an event listener only to elements that have id such as "disk*".

You are picking the id of those elements, and the id of their parent. The ID has no removeChild method, but that method is on the element theirself. In order to make your code work, you should change it as follow:

```
let chosenDisc
let chosenTower

disks.forEach((choice) => choices.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    chosenDisc = e.target 
    chosenTower = e.target.parentElement
    console.log(chosenDisc.id, " is in ", chosenTower.id)
    chosenTower.removeChild(chosenDisc)
    container.appendChild(chosenDisc)
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the forEach loop, you are assigning the id of the parent element to chosenTower.
chosenTower is not a node, it's just a string.

```
chosenTower = e.target.parentElement
```

would fix this.

Answer (score 0):

`removeChild` and `appendChild` are expecting a node object. you need to pass the target instead of the target.id for `chosenDisc`.

```js
let chosenDisc;
let chosenTower;

disks.forEach((choice) =>
   choices.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
     chosenDisc  = e.target;
     chosenTower = e.target.parentElement;
     console.log(chosenDisc, " is in ", chosenTower)
     chosenTower.removeChild(chosenDisc)
     container.appendChild(chosenDisc)
   })
)
```

```html
<article class="container"></article>
<section class="towers">
  <div class="tower" id="towerOne">
    <div class="disk" id="diskOne"></div>
    <div class="disk" id="diskTwo"></div>
    <div class="disk" id="diskThree"></div>
    <div class="disk" id="diskFour"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tower" id="torreTwo"></div>
  <div class="tower" id="torreThree"></div>
</section>
```